# If condition inside a target in a Makefile

Tags: makefile

I want to do something like this, where I want to run a svn commit if a file has changed. The file has a timestamp which always changes. So if anything more than timestamp changes , then I want to commit the file.

The makefile will have something similar to this. But the If condition is not working properly. It is getting executed even when if is not satisfied. Can someone help me out what is the problem in If here.

```
    UPDATE_STATE_FILE :
        $(eval NO_LINES_CHANGES_IN_STATE = $(shell svn di STATE/build.state --diff-cmd=diff -x --normal | grep "^[<>]" | wc -l))
        @echo $(NO_LINES_CHANGES_IN_STATE)
    ifneq ($(strip $(NO_LINES_CHANGES_IN_STATE)), 2)
    ifneq ($(strip $(NO_LINES_CHANGES_IN_STATE)), 0)
        @echo $(NO_LINES_CHANGES_IN_STATE)
        $(SVN) commit;
        $(SVN) update;
    endif
    endif
```

Comment: in the echo of the value for NO_LINES_CHANGES_IN_STATE, it is printing 0 even when the value is more than 2.

Answer (score 18):

You cannot mix make conditionals inside command rules.  Make conditionals are like preprocessor statements in C or C++; they are handled as the file is read in, before any processing (like running rules) is performed.

If you want conditionals inside the rules you have to write the rule using shell conditionals, not make conditionals:

```
UPDATE_STATE_FILE :
        @NO_LINES_CHANGES_IN_STATE=`svn di STATE/build.state --diff-cmd=diff -x --normal | grep "^[<>]" | wc -l`; \
        echo $$NO_LINES_CHANGES_IN_STATE; \
        if [ $$NO_LINES_CHANGES_IN_STATE -ne 2 ] && [ $$NO_LINES_CHANGES_IN_STATE -ne 0 ]; then \
            echo $$NO_LINES_CHANGES_IN_STATE; \
            $(SVN) commit; \
            $(SVN) update; \
        fi
```

Comment: In the above, if condition is working, but I am running the command `svn up` . It is throwing error       **/bin/sh: line 5: Updating: command not found
gmake: *** [UPDATE_STATE_FILE] Error 127**   Can you help me out on this.

Comment: Something is wrong in your script; probably a typo.  You should first remove the `@` prefix so you can see the command that make is running.  If that doesn't make the problem clear, try adding `set -x;` at the beginning of the script (before the first `echo`) so the shell will print the commands it's running.  Note that it's almost impossible for us to help you debug using SO comments because they don't preserve newlines etc.  Either open a new question, or edit your current question with the details.

Answer (score 3):

After reading the answer given by @MadScientist, I came up with a different approach.

Not knowing if shell conditionals will work in any environment (windows vs. linux), I wrapped the rules inside the conditional instead of having a conditional inside the rule. i.e.

```
ifdef MY_FLAG
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $^ $(CFLAGS)

else
%.o: %.c
    @$(CC) -o $@ -c $^ $(CFLAGS)

endif
```

Good luck to anyone visiting here.

**EDIT**

As pointed out by James Moore in the comments, this different approach requires care and notice as to when and how variables are defined in relation to the placement of the `if` statement in the control flow.

Comment: Keep in mind that this behavior is _completely_ different than putting conditionals in the target.  In particular, you need to think carefully about when variable expansion occurs; MY_FLAG could be set to something else later in the makefile, and what you're doing here isn't going to pick that up.

Comment: @JamesMoore , yes, the different approach has a different behavior - especially when things like `make`'s belated variable expansions might come into consideration... but this is - IMHO - what makes this approach more suitable in many situations. It might not fit perfectly with the question's specific use-case, but I thought it's important enough to point out. In many cases it will provide similar results using a more portable solution.